# Angular material: How to right align matInput placeholder?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this simple code:

```
<body style="direction: rtl; text-align: right">
    <mat-form-field>        
        <input matInput placeholder="Wanna be rtl" />
    </mat-form-field>
</body>
```

BUT no matter what I'm trying to, the placeholder keep acting as left to right. Is there any way to align it to the right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `text-align` on the form field will work: See working [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqcnrj)

**This solution will align both the placeholder and the input text to the right:**

```
<body>
    <mat-form-field style="text-align: right">        
        <input matInput placeholder="Wanna be rtl" />
    </mat-form-field>
</body>
```

**Result:**
[image]

If you **want to only align the placeholder to the right and keep the input text aligned left** then add `style="text-align: left"` to the input as shown below

```
<body>
    <mat-form-field style="text-align: right">        
        <input matInput placeholder="Wanna be rtl" style="text-align: left"/>
    </mat-form-field>
</body>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Won't seem to work with Angular 15 MDC-based Angular Material Components anymore. `text-align: right` on `mat-form-field` wont change anything, already tried to apply it on sub-elements (::ng-deep) with no success.

Answer (score 3):

After sometime I came across the sass of the `mat-form-field` and I found out that if the parent of the `mat-form-field` has `dir="rtl"` attribute, it acts as rtl:

```
<body dir="rtl">
   <mat-form-field>        
       <input matInput placeholder="I am rtl" />
   </mat-form-field>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Bidirectionality](https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/overview) module in CDK:

```
import {BidiModule} from '@angular/cdk/bidi';

...

<body dir="rtl">
    <mat-form-field>        
        <input matInput placeholder="I am RTL" />
    </mat-form-field>
</body>
```