# How do you change whole <mat-form-field> direction to right?

Tags: angular, direction

My code contains:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>טלפון</mat-label>
    <input name="phone"[(ngModel)]="user.phone"  matInput/>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Possible solution's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289197/angular-material-how-to-right-align-matinput-placeholder

Comment: Thanks Nadar, you helped me. The solution was to add "text-align:right" to the whole mat-form-field.